# How to drop a class (table) in Back4app Dashboard

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I'm new to parse and back4app. While I'm trying to delete a class (table) in the dashboard, I can't find any menu item that allows me to do it. Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Also related, is it possible to change a column's name after it is added, and is it possible to bulk update rows for certain fields, all within the dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually I just found part of the answer. The "Delete this class" menu item is in the top right Edit menu, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the class, it must be empty, so you firstly need to delete all rows before deleting the class.

It's not possible to edit the column's name from the dashboard, so, what you may do is exporting the data and import your JSON file with the right name.

Another option that is not recommended if you're not sure about it, is updating the column's name through Mongo commands.

You'll need to update it in the collection (the class) and in the SCHEMAS too.

The connection string to help you with the mongo commands is available at Server Settings > Core Settings > Settings > MongoDB Database URI.